# Select xs:element from xdocument in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have an xdocument which contains several sets of data and I would like to be able to select the data for specific xs:element.

For example I have this block of code:

```
// get xml string
var xmlResponse = _traineeCommands.GetTraineeDetails(personId.ToString());

// parse to xdocument
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlResponse);

// select specific element and children
var traineeDetails = doc.Descendants("xs:element")
     .Select(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == "TraineeDetails");
```

This is my stack trace:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.Xml.XmlException",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Xml.XmlConvert.VerifyNCName(String name, ExceptionType exceptionType)\r\n   at System.Xml.Linq.XName..ctor(XNamespace ns, String localName)\r\n   at System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace.GetName(String localName)\r\n   at IceServices.IpdApi.Controllers.JobController.GetTraineeDetailsForIpd(Int32 personId) in C:\\Users\\GOWDY_N\\Source\\Repos\\IceServices\\IceServices.IpdApi\\Controllers\\JobController.cs:line 134\r\n   at IceServices.IpdApi.Controllers.JobController.<Get>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\\Users\\GOWDY_N\\Source\\Repos\\IceServices\\IceServices.IpdApi\\Controllers\\JobController.cs:line 66\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

This is the whole xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetIPDTraineeDetailsResponse
            xmlns="http://iris.co.uk/">
            <GetIPDTraineeDetailsResult>
                <xs:schema id="NewDataSet"
                    xmlns=""
                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:element name="TraineeDetails">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="TRAINEE_ID" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="ORG_REGISTRATION_ID" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="TRAINING_SCHEME_TITLE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="SELF_MANAGED" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="TRAINING_START_DATE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="ANNUAL_REVIEW_STATUS" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="SCE_ID" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="SCE_FORENAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="SCE_SURNAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="SCE_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="DE_ID" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="DE_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="DE_PERSON_ID" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="DE_FORENAMES" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="DE_FORENAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="DE_SURNAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="DE_EMAIL_ADDRESS" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MENTOR_ID" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MENTOR_FORENAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MENTOR_SURNAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MENTOR_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MENTOR_EMAIL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="MENTOR_PERSONID" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="SELECTED_LEVEL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="SELECTED_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="TRAINEE_STATUS" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="TRAINEE_STATUS_DESCR" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="REQUESTED_DE_PERSON_ID" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="REQUESTED_DE_SURNAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="REQUESTED_DE_FORENAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="PENDING_DE_EMAIL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                                <xs:element name="PersonDetails">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="FORENAMES" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="FORENAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="SURNAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="DOB" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="EMPLOYER_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="EMPLOYER_ADDRESS_1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="EMPLOYER_ADDRESS_2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="EMPLOYER_ADDRESS_3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="EMPLOYER_TOWN" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="EMPLOYER_STATE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="EMPLOYER_COUNTRY" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="EMPLOYER_POSTCODE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="REASON_NOT_WORKING" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="IPD_STATUS" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="PAYMENT_RECEIVED" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="SM_PRODUCT_DESC" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="SM_PRODUCT_PRICE" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="ORIGINAL_TRAINING_START_DATE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="REVIEW_DATE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="TRANSFER_DATE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="ELIGIBLE_LEVEL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="ELIGIBLE_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="DEFAULT_LEVEL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="DEFAULT_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="PERSON_AIM" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="EMPLOYEE_NUMBER" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="IPD_SIGNUP_DATE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="REQUESTED_MENTOR_PERSON_ID" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="REQUESTED_MENTOR_SURNAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="REQUESTED_MENTOR_FORENAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="PENDING_MENTOR_EMAIL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="PENDING_AIM" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:schema>
                <diffgr:diffgram
                    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
                    xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                    <NewDataSet
                        xmlns="">
                        <TraineeDetails diffgr:id="TraineeDetails1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                            <ID>40798297</ID>
                            <SELF_MANAGED>0</SELF_MANAGED>
                        </TraineeDetails>
                        <PersonDetails diffgr:id="PersonDetails1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                            <ID>40798297</ID>
                            <FORENAMES>Alan Gibson</FORENAMES>
                            <FORENAME>Alan</FORENAME>
                            <SURNAME>Mordey</SURNAME>
                            <DOB>21/10/1945</DOB>
                            <EMPLOYER_NAME>Atkins</EMPLOYER_NAME>
                            <EMPLOYER_ADDRESS_1>The Axis</EMPLOYER_ADDRESS_1>
                            <EMPLOYER_ADDRESS_2>10 Holliday Street</EMPLOYER_ADDRESS_2>
                            <EMPLOYER_TOWN>BIRMINGHAM</EMPLOYER_TOWN>
                            <EMPLOYER_STATE>West Midlands</EMPLOYER_STATE>
                            <EMPLOYER_COUNTRY>UK</EMPLOYER_COUNTRY>
                            <EMPLOYER_POSTCODE>B1 1TF</EMPLOYER_POSTCODE>
                            <IPD_STATUS>0</IPD_STATUS>
                            <PAYMENT_RECEIVED>0</PAYMENT_RECEIVED>
                            <SM_PRODUCT_DESC>Mentor Support Training</SM_PRODUCT_DESC>
                            <SM_PRODUCT_PRICE>340.75</SM_PRODUCT_PRICE>
                            <ELIGIBLE_LEVEL>UNK</ELIGIBLE_LEVEL>
                            <ELIGIBLE_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION>Unknown</ELIGIBLE_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION>
                            <DEFAULT_LEVEL>ENGTECH</DEFAULT_LEVEL>
                            <DEFAULT_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION>EngTech</DEFAULT_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION>
                            <PERSON_AIM>CENG</PERSON_AIM>
                        </PersonDetails>
                    </NewDataSet>
                </diffgr:diffgram>
            </GetIPDTraineeDetailsResult>
        </GetIPDTraineeDetailsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to select xs:element TraineeDetails in my schema and return the data as a value i.e. IEnumerable of values, in this case IEnumerable of XElements. This would bring back these values:

```
<TraineeDetails diffgr:id="TraineeDetails1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
    <ID>40798297</ID>
    <SELF_MANAGED>0</SELF_MANAGED>
</TraineeDetails>
```

Any ideas? It's seems like it should be simple but I get that stack trace error on selecting descendants.

Comment: Try this : var traineeDetails = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "element")

Comment: Please avoid posting information that is fundamentally text as images. You could very easily have copied and pasted the text into the question - or better, produced a *minimal* version as part of a [mcve].

Comment: Additionally, that XML isn't the actual *data*, it's just the schema...

Comment: @JonSkeet I've removed the image and replaced it with the XML string.

Comment: (Sigh) You didn't bother to format it though, did you? Please be more respectful of the time of other people, and use the preview to check that the result is as readable as *you'd* want it to be if you were trying to help someone. I've formatted it now, but please do so yourself in future. Now, there's still the problem that that's the schema, not the actual data set.

Comment: Ah, and now you've replaced it with completely different data... at which point the question makes no sense, as you're asking for `xs:element` when there's no sign of that anywhere...

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated the question so it makes more sense and it can help the community. Here is an XML, I would like to select xs:element based on the schema and return that data so I can assign it to a variable, in this case IEnumerable of XElements.

Comment: I don't think it makes very much sense, to be honest. Surely you just ignore the schema entirely, and instead treat the `diffgr:diffgram` as the root of the actual data set. This is just a matter of looking at the XML and asking yourself where the data you actually want is - and it's *not* in the schema.

Comment: @JonSkeet What would you recommend instead?

Comment: Instead of what? The current question? Well, it seems like you basically didn't take enough time to work out where the data was before asking. After doing that, is there still a useful question? If so, what is it? Which part of "find the right element once you actually know which element you want" is difficult? *That* would be a useful question - but "I didn't really look at where the data was closely enough" isn't, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet The intention of the question was how to programmatically retrieve the data for TraineeDetails from the XML using C#. I've followed your suggestions because SO is important to the community and It's important to follow the guidelines. For what it's worth I think this post is useful for anyone who uses google to find an answer related to XML and C# but if you think that isn't the case, moderate this post as you see fit. Thanks for your help, Nick

Comment: But your sample code tries to find the `xs:element` element - why would it do that? There are lots of questions about how to find a particular element in LINQ to XML - the problem here appears to be that you were looking for the wrong element, and I don't think that's a useful SO question, as it's not really a code problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no namespace declaration for the `xs` prefix in the XML you show. Is your XML file in order, or are you missing this?

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

If not, make sure you add the namespace too whenever you query prefixed elements:

```
XNamespace xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = doc.Descendants(xs + "element");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on feedback in this post, you can use this to select the descendants and return back an IEnumerable of XElements:

```
var traineeDetails = xDocument.Descendants("TraineeDetails");
```

It's also possible to use LINQ in C# to select these values but I ended up using option 1:

```
var traineeDetails = from c in doc.Descendants("TraineeDetails ") select c;
```

Comment: Um, why use `from...select` when that's basically equivalent to `var traineeDetails = doc.Descendants("TraineeDetails");`? I suspect you don't really have a space at the end, either...

Comment: Also, I don't think that code would select elements in the XML you showed, which is basically the schema, not the actual data.

Comment: @JonSkeet My mistake, I've updated the question with the XML data (not the schema of the XML).